# Migrating Sequelize migrations

Tags: sails.js, sequelize.js

I recently started working on a Sails project. It currently has migrations under migrations table with the following format.

```
20160826122004-create_users_table.js

'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, DataTypes, done) {
    var users= queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
      },
    })
    .then(function() {
      done();
    })
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  }
};
```

However, there is no reference to those migrations in the codebase. Anyone knows how to run migrations since doing `sails lift` does nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your code you should not assign the `queryInterface` method to variable, instead `return` it:

```
...
return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
...
```

The same in the `down` function:

```
return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
```

What is more, in order to reflect those changes in the database, you should use the [sequelize-cli](https://github.com/sequelize/cli). You can run migrations via `sequelize db:migrate`. You can also use `sequelize help` in order to get more information concerning commands and options of the CLI.